# Python Pandas: How to select the index of the min from one column and use that to select index for other columns after a grouby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 'b':[-0.1,-0.2,-0.1,-0.1,-0.005,-0.3,0,-0.9,-0.6],'name':['fast','slow1','slow2','slow1','fast1','fast1','slow','fast','slow1']})
```

**Output**

```
    a     b      name
0   1   -0.100  fast
1   2   -0.200  slow1
2   2   -0.100  slow2
3   3   -0.100  slow1
4   3   -0.005  fast1
5   3   -0.300  fast1
6   4   0.000   slow
7   4   -0.900  fast
8   4   -0.600  slow1
```

I am grouping it by column "a"

```
df.groupby(by=["a"]).agg({"b":"min"})
```

```
    b
a   
1   -0.1
2   -0.2
3   -0.3
4   -0.9
```

How do I select the corresponding "name" column for the min index of column "b"? What I am trying to get at is this:

```
    b     name
a   
1   -0.1  fast
2   -0.2  slow1
3   -0.3  fast1
4   -0.9  fast
```

I tried using the "apply" method but for large dataframes it was getting really slow. Is there a way to use the "agg" function here?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can easily do it using `groupby.min()`.

```
dd.groupby('a').min()
Out[250]: 
     b   name
a            
1 -0.1   fast
2 -0.2  slow1
3 -0.3  fast1
4 -0.9   fast
```

Comment: Interesting. Iupvoted.

Comment: How does this work if there is one more column called "c" with different numbers? Will "name" be chosen from the first column's idxmin?

Comment: I did a small experiment by adding another column and it is using the first column (in this case "b") to select the "name"

Comment: I have tried with multiple columns too. Apparently, my method works for one column of value. For multiple columns of values, you can refer to the answer by @SomeDude.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas.Series.idxmin):

```
res = df.groupby(by=["a"]).agg({"b": ["min", pd.NamedAgg(column="name", aggfunc=lambda x: df["name"].iloc[x.idxmin()])]})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
     b       
   min   name
a            
1 -0.1   fast
2 -0.2  slow1
3 -0.3  fast1
4 -0.9   fast
```

Comment: Can you help me explain what the 'x' in the pd.NamedAgg is referring to?

Comment: @Kranthi The x is referring to the column "b"

Comment: Thank you! This is a very interesting way!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].idxmin()].set_index('a')
```

output:

```
     b   name
a            
1 -0.1   fast
2 -0.2  slow1
3 -0.3  fast1
4 -0.9   fast
```